# Prefetch the contents of files referenced by the ORM

Tags: django

My situation is that I'm using the Django ORM to fetch a list of objects, each with a file. I then need to access the file-data for each and every object in the list. We're hosting our files on S3, and it seems to take a long time every time I call `f.read()`

I'm wondering, is there a way to pre-fetch the contents of the file, so that f.read() doesn't have to make another round-trip?

Anything else I can do to speed this up? Any help is appreciated, and let me know if there is more I can clarify.

Comment: Not clear what you're doing with the files: are they just being served to the end-user or do you need to read them in python to process them?

Comment: Which storage backend are you using? This one? https://django-storages.readthedocs.io/en/latest/backends/amazon-S3.html#amazon-s3

Comment: Read them in python to process, and yes, django-storages. I'm just wondering if there's a way that the text can be pre-fetched. It feels unlikely that django would do it in a way that's at all parallel though, because of its single-threaded nature, but I figure its worth asking